# IIS 7 certificate import without the private key

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to import a .cer file into IIS certificates section without having the private key ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you can't use it to serve a website.

IIS only allows the import of `.pfx` files through its interface, but if you have a `.cer` file you can import it via MMC by adding the `Certificates/Computer` addin.